# PasswordSignInAsync MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

Good day, Please i am writing an MVC application that can only allow users sign in with three parameters which are ID,Email and password. My question is the PasswordSignInAsync has two major parameters Email and Password. How can i override it to allow ID as another parameter for the sign in.

this is the normal code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result =  await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("DealerDashboard", "Dealers");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

//so in my solution i want to do this:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result =  await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.id,model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("DealerDashboard", "Dealers");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The whole framework is extendable and almost nothing is sealed. Why don't you try it and see how far you get. If you run into a problem come back with the details and post the specifics.

Comment: Why do you want to use ID, is the username not unique?

Comment: i have many users that share the ID for a particular company.so i want each individual user to login with id,email and password.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, as Igor says you just need to override `SignInManager`. Something like this:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, Guid>
{

    // adjust as needed
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userId, string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = await base.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        // do validation for user, etc.

        return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
    }
}
```